# NSArray is not overwritting on viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a menu with two items, Login and Settings, displayed in a tableView. Login and Settings are stored in an NSArray. On ViewDidLoad I am checking if user exist in NSUserDefaults. If user exist then change the Login to Logout and vice versa. The issue is that on ViewDidLoad it only changes the name once when the application is opened after being cleared from cache. Therefore, in order to see the change after login in or login out you need to clear the application from cache and re-open it. I want the changes to apply immediately. Every time the menu button click before the menu open and viewDidAppear is accessed. I know this because I placed a break point and traced it. It does what is supposed to. But the it never changes the value of login to logout or vice versa.

MenuController.

```
-(void)ChangeLoginLabel {
    NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *User = [data objectForKey:@"User"];
    if(User==nil) {
        _extraMenuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Settings", @"Login", nil];
    }
    else {
        _extraMenuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Settings", @"Logout", nil];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self ChangeLoginLabel];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self ChangeLoginLabel];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    return self.extraMenuItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Formal";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.extraTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *cellValue = [self.extraMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Settings cell tapped!");
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        //closes when login view appears
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];

        NSString *LoginTextLabel = [self.extraMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([LoginTextLabel isEqualToString:@"Logout"]) {
        }
        else {
            UIViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
    // Deselect the row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 }
```

Logs

```
2014-12-12 13:06:53.290 xxx[1695:270056] _extraMenuItems: (
    Settings,
    Login
)
2014-12-12 13:07:04.290 xxx[1695:270056] _extraMenuItems: (
    Settings,
    Logout
)
```

How can I force the array to change the value immediately when the user logged in or logged out?

Comment: how do you know the extraMenuItems array is NOT changing value? (I suspect it is, actually.) What is not happening that you want to happen? Perhaps you need to invoke some other piece of code you have not shared which uses this array to build up some UI?

Comment: Where and when is [data objectForKey:@"User"] set?

If this isn't set when you expect it to be, User will always be nil and the menu item will always be Login.

Comment: Changed to Array to Mutable array but logic stays the same

Comment: No it is set properly. I traced it with break point it enters the correct statement. for some very strange reason it does not change the value of the string

Comment: Is there anywhere else where self.extraMenuItems is changed?

Comment: No I pasted the entire code

Comment: This is very strange

Comment: Could you post the code where you set [data objectForKey:@"User"]?

Comment: I'm asking because I suspect you're not calling `synchronize`.

Comment: If you add NSLog(@"_extraMenuItems: %@", [_extraMenuItems description]); immediately after _extraMenuItems is set, what does it log?

Comment: @Program_ming : check my answer... hope it will solve....

Comment: @ateich I did it and it displays (above in my code)

Comment: @Program_ming Like I mentioned, are you sure you're *synchronizing* your NSUserDefaults update?

Comment: I do not think the problem is with the user default. Instead the issue is with changing the text in the cells

Comment: @Program_ming I was confused by the wording of your question, but I think I understand what you're saying now... Will write up an answer in a bit.

Comment: Ok thank you, I am sorry to confuse you.

Comment: Your numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath, and didSelectRowAtIndexPath say self.extraMenuItems as opposed to _extraMenuItems which is set in ChangeLoginLabel.

Comment: While _ and self should reference the same thing, try changing _extraMenuItems to self.extraMenuItems, just in case.

Comment: @Program_ming Check out my answer. I think the major problem is that you fail to reload your table's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're trying to update the label in your table based on the change in `NSUserDefaults` as triggered by a login/logout from another view controller; so when you return to the `MenuViewController`, `ChangeLoginLabel` is triggered by the `viewDidAppear`, the `extraMenuItems` array is in fact set to contain the appropriate values, and you expect the labels in the table to change accordingly. But the problem is, that you're not reloading the table upon your return to the view.

So first off, I'd recommend removing `[self ChangeLoginLabel];` from your `viewDidLoad` since it's redundant. And secondly, I'd recommend changing your `ChangeLoginLabel` method to include a table reload, like so:

```
-(void)ChangeLoginLabel {

    NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *User = [data objectForKey:@"User"];
    if(User==nil) {
        self.extraMenuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Settings", @"Login", nil];
    }
    else {
        self.extraMenuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Settings", @"Logout", nil];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self ChangeLoginLabel];
}
```

Or if you'd prefer just to reload the relevant row you can replace `[self.tableView reloadData];` with:

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want `viewWillAppear` instead?  `viewDidAppear` happens after the view already is rendered I believe.

Answer (score 1):

call

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self ChangeLoginLabel];
}
```

or

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDifAppear:animated];
    [self ChangeLoginLabel];
}
```

Comment: Does not work. Non of the it. Both nor one at the time.

Comment: @Program_ming put a NSLog in both method.  Make sure they get called.